# nouislider with livewire how to get values

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How can i get the values from nouislider in livewire? So i can compare the min and max price. I don't see how i can get the values. It has 2 handles a min and max price.

```
         <div wire:ignore id="slider-margin"></div>
                        <div class="d-flex">

                            <div wire:model="min_price" class="me-5" id="slider-margin-value-min" aria-valuenow="min_price"></div>
                            <div wire:model="max_price" id="slider-margin-value-max" aria-valuemax="max_price"></div>

                        </div>
```

```
class Shop extends Component
{
use WithPagination;
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
public $min_price;
public $max_price;

public function render()
    {
 $this->products = Product::query()
 ->wherebetween('price',[$this->min_price,$this->max_price])->paginate(9);

        return view('livewire.shop',[
            'products'=>$this->products
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<div wire:ignore id="slider-margin"></div>
<div class="d-flex">

    <div wire:click="setMin({{ $min_price }})" class="me-5" id="slider-margin-value-min" aria-valuenow="min_price"></div>
    <div wire:click="setMax({{ $max_price }})" id="slider-margin-value-max" aria-valuemax="max_price"></div>
</div>
```

and:

```
class Shop extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    public $min_price;
    public $max_price;

    public function setMax($max_price)
    {
        $this->max_price= $max_price;
    }

    public function setMin($min_price)
    {
        $this->min_price = $min_price;
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->products = Product::query()
            ->wherebetween('price',[$this->min_price,$this->max_price])->paginate(9);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunally

Comment: Use your query instead of the render function in the mount function
I modified the above code

Answer (score 0):

A div is no input, so a `wire:model` won't do anything on it. noUiSlider builds HTML after page load, so to be able to use it for variables in Livewire, you will have to use JavaScript. You can listen for the [events](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/) and use the [global Livewire JS object](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#from-js) to emit changes to your component

So, an example of how this might work:

```js
let slider = document.getElementById('slider-margin');

slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values) {
    Livewire.emitTo('shop', 'sliderUpdated', values);
});
```

Then in your component, you can do something with the passed values:

```php
function sliderUpdated(array $values) 
{
   $this->min_price = \Illuminate\Support\Arr::first($values);
}
```

Ensure to take a good read on the event docs, as I am not 100% sure above code will function straight away, but I think this will at least get you in the right direction!